# Construction of two graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I would like to know if it is possible to construct two graphs $G,H$ such that $|G|=|H|, e(G)=e(H)$ (means that the two graphs have the same number of vertices and edges) and $\chi(G)>\chi(H)$ where $\chi()$ represents the chromatic number, such that there are more ways to colour $G$ than $H$ when the number of available colours is large.

It would be great if you have some ideas.

Comment: Could you clarify "there are more ways to colour G than H when the number of available colours is large"? Once the number of colors exceeds the number of vertices, there should be the same number of colorings on each graph.

Comment: The statement simply refers to the property that $\chi(G)>\chi(H)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first graph contains a copy of $K_4$, so it requires $4$ colors.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the graph on RHS representing?

Comment: @Montaigne: It’s simply another graph with $7$ vertices and $9$ edges but with a smaller chromatic number, as demonstrated by the numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a square. Let $H$ be a triangle with a single extra vertex attached to one corner.

$|G|=|H|=4$ and $e(G)=e(H)=4$. $G$ can be colored with $2$ colors, but $H$ requires $3$, since it contains a triangle.

Have I misunderstood the question?